# Determining if front or rear camera was used to capture video

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to determine whether the front or rear camera was used to record a video that is selected from the camera roll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any meta-data or property associated with video's that Apple requires to be present for video's in your camera roll that could tell you this. And since you can't control where the clips on the camera roll came from, you have to rely on the absolute minimum amount of meta-data required for that file format.

Case in point, there is no guarantee whatsoever that a clip was even taken from a camera at all. If someone texted you a video file that they created from software, and you saved it to your camera roll, the concept of "Front or rear" camera would make no sense at all.

You could certainly keep track of clips that your app takes by storing them in a folder within your app and associating a camera position with each unique clip name, (`[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]` is great for this)